# failed to insert multiple data in mysqli using loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to store one's friends of facebook into a table. The result of below code shows only a single record is inserted. It wasn't the problem of my loop because I echo the name, it all appeared.

```
    foreach($user_friends['data'] as $friend){

        //echo $friend['name'] . "</br>";

    $userImg = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$friend['id']."/picture?width=200&height=200"; 
    $friendsName = $friend['name'];

    $stmt3 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO allfriend(`uId`,`name`,`img`,`friendOf`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt3->bind_param('ssss', $user_fbid, $friendsName, $userImg, $user_fbid);
    $stmt3->execute();

}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `prepare` and `bind_param` each time. Call them both before the loop, then just call `execute` inside the loop.

Comment: Check for errors: `$stmt3 = $db->prepare("INSERT ...") or die ($db->error)` and `$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the prepare / bind feature slightly. You only need to prepare once, but you do need to reset the statement after each use.

Also, you should check for failure of your statements. If you do that you may find out why things might work differently from what you expect.

Is it possible your column `friend.uID` is in fact a primary key? The code you've shown tries to insert the same value into multiple rows. That could be your problem.

Try this:

```
$stmt3 = $db->prepare
         ("INSERT INTO allfriend(`uId`,`name`,`img`,`friendOf`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
   || die "prepare failed: ". $db->error;

foreach($user_friends['data'] as $friend) {

    //echo $friend['name'] . "</br>";

    $userImg = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$friend['id']."/picture?width=200&height=200"; 
    $friendsName = $friend['name'];

    $stmt3->bind_param('ssss', $user_fbid, $friendsName, $userImg, $user_fbid)
        || die "bind_param failed " . $db->error;

    $stmt3->execute()
        || die "execute failed " . $db->error;

    $stmt3->reset()
        || die "reset failed " . $db->error;

}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"prepare failed: "'

Comment: Well, if SO's purpose was delivering perfectly tested code, that would be a problem. But the purpose is to help us learn from each other.